# При попытке установки Vowpal wabbit появляется ошибка, которую я не могу понять

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Скачал ноутбук с каггл, про vowpal wabbit tutorial.
В нём есть код:

```
%%capture
!git clone --recursive https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit.git 
!cd vowpal_wabbit/; make 
!cd vowpal_wabbit/; make install
```

затем вот такой код:

```
!vw --help
```

И вот после этого кода выходит вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что не так? Может установка не правильная? И почему у меня на компьютере, иногда, в выводе кода появляются кракозябры?
У меня виндовз 10.

Comment: А до `!vw --help` не ругается, нормально всё поставило?

Comment: Это windows пишет, что не находит команды vw. Кракозябры - потому что windows думает, что пишет в консоль, поэтому пишет кодировкой cp866, а у вас выводится в jupyter notebook, скорее всего он декодирует кодировкой cp1251.

Comment: До !vw --help всё нормально, ничего не выводиться.

Comment: В нотебуке можно поменять кодировку для нормального отображения выводов?